# How to open multiple files in one ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avaudioplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

i want to make ios app with Xcode and Swift , but my problem is that i have multiple buttons on Main Screen which will open in One ViewController named TextViewVC , i have done this for text file but i am unable to do with mp3 file, i mean on main screen if user click on Button1 then TextFile1 should open in TextViewVC and in TextViewVc there is Play Button and when user click on Play Button then Audio1 should play, And So For Button2 , when user click on it TextFile2 should open in TextViewVc and in TextViewVc when user click on Play Button then Audio2 should play.

This Is My Main Screen
[image]

and this is TextViewVC where Play Button Is Integreted
[image]

and this is my code to open textfile in TextViewVC

```
  if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "txt") {
        do {
            let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath)
            print(contents)
            //  Now push second ViewController form here with contents.
               if let secondVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TextViewVC") as? TextViewVC {
                secondVC.content = contents
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
```

i want to play different Audio File On Different Buttons, Thanks

Comment: Just create your all button action and also create a file name variable at the top of the class when you click on particular button just fill the filename in that button action and then pass that file name to another class and it will work for you. Hope it will work for you.

Comment: sorry i am new to Xcode, can you please give me code ? @VipinPareek

Answer (score 0):

create object class and pass object class to second viewController like

```
let dict : [String : Any] = ["name": "type of songs you want name","mp3" : AudioFileObject,"msg" : "message"]
```

and where from your keys you can use conditions for different buttons.